# Show message and lock word document, if Addin is not installed

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I am working on addin for Word 2013. If document is created using my addin then it should be locked if the addin is not available or installed.

Is it possible using VSTO addin?

Comment: Well, you have to lock it on safe and unlock it when your addin is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, does that mean there is no way to inform end user, about nonavailability of addin?

Comment: If you think about it, if the add-in is not there then what should do the checking? Another add-in? The only other way would be code inside the document (whether VBA or VSTO) that checks whether the add-in is loaded.

Comment: Sorry for late response Cindy. I am thinking of same way e.g. My custom plugin will insert macro while document is being created. I googled but looks like it is possible to insert macro in docx files.

Comment: It's not possible to insert a macro in a docx, it must be a docm. Note that this could trigger macro warnings or not load, so you want to research the "Trust Center" settings. Note: it is possible to digitally sign VBA (macro) code. If that's how your VSTO add-in is being "trusted" then the same signature should work for the macro code. HOWEVER I believe it is NOTpossible to digitally sign a macro using the VBA code interface (not secure). So it might make sense to include a signed dotm template as part of your add-in "package" and use that to create your documents.